# Loop through multiple folder and Calculate mean of raster of Same folder R

Tags: r, loops, raster, subdirectory, batch-rename

I am looking to loop through different subfolders in a parent folder in R. I precise that I am a new user of R. I have 10 subfolders that are in 1 parent folder. Each of the subfolders contains 100 rasters files. 
For each of the subfolder I would like to calculate the mean of all the raster files and write the new raster based on the name of the subfolder and add the description "mean".

```
             |--Subfol i=1 --[raster(j=1), 
             |                 raster(j),    --mean 100 files -- Subfol1mean.        |
             |                raster(j=100)]
             |
parent_fold--|
             |
             |----Subfol i=1 --[raster(j=1),
                                raster(j),    --mean 100 files -- Subfol10mean.
                                raster(j=100)]
```

I tried the following code to start:

```
 setwd("XXXX/parent_fold")
#list all the files in the subfolders
sub<- list.files(full.names = F , recursive =F, pattern='tiff')
for(j in 1:length(sub)){
h<- list.files(path=sub[j], recursive = T, full.names = T,    pattern='tiff')
d<-stack(h)
x<-stackApply(d, mean)
#writeRaster
}
```

I have some difficulties to pursue and I am not sure what I did I the correct path. Thanks for any help.

I got the following error:

```
 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
 unable to find an inherited method for function ‘nlayers’ for   signature ‘"matrix"’
```

Comment: If you are having difficulties you need to explain in detail (with full text of messages in the question body, not in comments here) what sort of difficulties: errors?, warnings? unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Below a solution that works well: 

setwd("XXX/parent_fold")
library(raster)
sub <- list.dirs(full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)

for(j in 1:length(sub)) {
print(sub[j])

h <- list.files(path=sub[j], recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE,  pattern='.tiff')
print(h)

d <- stack(h)
mean <- stackApply(d, indices =  rep(1,nlayers(d)), fun = "mean", na.rm = T)

writeRaster(mean, filename=paste0(sub[j], "_mean.tif"), overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you want to first iterate through `list.dirs` for subfolders and then `list.files` for corresponding files. Right now, your looping will return nothing as *sub* would be empty. Consider placing `print` statements to verify.

```
sub <- list.dirs(full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)

for(j in 1:length(sub)) {
  print(sub[j])

  h <- list.files(path=sub[j], recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, pattern='.tiff')
  print(h)

  d <- stack(h)
  x <- stackApply(d, mean)

  writeRaster(x, filename=paste0(sub[j], "_mean.tiff"), format="****", overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

Please adjust last lines as needed as I know nothing of working with rasterfiles or *raster* package. Files will save in parent folder.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I tested your code but I got this error.              :Error in ind[] <- indices : 
  incompatible types (from closure to logical) in subassignment type fix

Comment: That must be one of the *raster* lines which I had pleaded you adjust yourself as I know nothing about *raster*. Does the `print` output show exactly the `.tiff` files? Possibly one of the inputs are not suitable.

Comment: No the code stoped before this print. The code print all my subfolder sub but not my files.

Comment: Really? I just copied and pasted exact code here and removed the *raster* lines. Code indeed prints all files in subfolders by the pattern. Even if there are no such extensions, empty lists are printed. Did you `setwd()`?

Comment: I tested on another computer, and it works but I have an error in stack apply that I need to fix. However, I do not understand why it works on a Mac and no a pc..

Comment: I'm working from a PC. Try a new clean R environment (i.e., close/re-open R session). Are you running in virtual env? Via a server with no filesystem?

Comment: No, but I think it is because I did not close R for a long time. I know that sometimes it can bug. I found a solution that works and writes my raster. I will post it. Thanks a lot for your help.